# Angular, ng-repeat and radio buttons

Tags: javascript, angularjs, radio-button

I am using radio buttons in a ng-repeat and it seems to have some problem. Basically, they work, however the user has to click on the radio button twice to uncheck itself and I can't seem to figure out why. Here's how I'm using it.

```
<div ng-repeat="parent in chains track by $index"><!-- Level 1 row -->
    <input type="radio" name="levelCheckDat" ng-model="trackChain.value" ng-value="{{$index}}" ng-change="trackLevelIndex()"> 
    <p style="font-weight:bold;">Chain {{$index+1}}</p>
</div>
```

It comes through the repeat, but it only will start working after you click on it twice. Any insight into this?

The ng- change just sets a boolean so I know something is select like so :

```
$scope.trackLevelIndex = function(){
    //update index for tracking what level we have selected
    $scope.levelChecked = true;
};
```

Then I use the trackChain.value to tell me what level is selected.

Comment: Please show us the javascript too. The ngChange action especially.

Comment: I added it, the ng-change doesn't really do too much though.

Comment: @ajmajmajma: Can you please explain what is wrong for you with this code? I created plunk, everything seems to be working. http://plnkr.co/edit/WqXuKzhT5BoLisB4ITbP?p=preview

Comment: @ababashka hmm - thanks for answering, I am loading all the stuff on the page with an $http before I run it through he repeat, I'm starting to think based on what you showed me it might have to do with that. Thank you for the example!